# Возможно ли заменить несколько файлов в подмодуле без создания форка?

Tags: git, git-submodule

В настоящий момент я разрабатываю игру на основе cocos2d-x, при этом движок подключен как подмодуль. Для интеграции компонентов SDKBOX требуется пропатчить несколько файлов, находящихся в подмодуле.

Возможно ли это без создания форка cocos2d-x и использования отдельного репозитория с наложенными патчами или копирования всего кода движка в основной репозиторий? Эти варианты нежелательны по ряду причин:

- Сложность обновления из оригинального репозитория
- Не хотелось бы
  делать публичный репозиторий с патченными файлами, но проект
  cocos2d-x находится на платформе GitHub, а мой — на BitBucket.

Comment: Строго говоря, ваша рабочая копия - это уже отдельный репозиторий с форком.